# How do I create voltage ripple for the purpose of testing?

Tags: voltage

I am aware of the solution to reduce ripple in circuits using smoothing capacitors.  But I want to create varying levels of ripple to stress test some scenarios where the power supply is not optimal.  Is there some way to create ripple into my test circuit?

Comment: use smaller value capacitors for a given load

Comment: What kind of ripple do you want to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a power supply, with a small series resistor, going to the load under test, to provide the current.

Also going to the load under test, an 8 ohm resistor and a large capacitor in series, driven from an audio power amplifier, to provide the ripple.

Drive the amplifier input with your chosen ripple source, either real ripple, or create a wav with a simulator, and play it into the amplifier.

Comment: Thank you. I just had one of those "Why didn't I think of that" moments.